# SAX XML parser - localized error messages

Tags: java, xml-parsing, localization, saxparser, xerces2-j

The web-application I am currently working on, validates user-supplied xml files against xsd stored on a server. The problem is that if xml fails validation, error messages should be in Russian. I have my parser working - it gives error messages but only in English

```
    String parserClass = "org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser";
    String validationFeature = "http://xml.org/sax/features/validation";
    String schemaFeature = "http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema";
    XMLReader reader = null;
    reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(parserClass);

    reader.setFeature(validationFeature,true);
    reader.setFeature(schemaFeature,true);

    BatchContentHandler contentHandler = new BatchContentHandler(reader);
    reader.setContentHandler(contentHandler);

    BatchErrorHandler errorHandler = new BatchErrorHandler(reader);
    reader.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);

    reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/continue-after-fatal-error", true);
    reader.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(streamedXML)));
```

It works fine - error messages are in English.
Reading this post [Locale specific messages in Xerces 2.11.0 (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531633/locale-specific-messages-in-xerces-2-11-0-java) and also this post https://www.java.net//node/699069 I added these lines

```
Locale l = new Locale("ru", "RU");
reader.setProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/locale", l);
```

I also added XMLSchemaMessages_RU.properties file to the jar. Now I get NULL pointer exception. Any ideas or hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found [here](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/properties.html) this about `http://apache.org/xml/properties/locale`:

> - Desc:The locale to use for reporting errors and warnings. When the value of this property is null the platform default returned from
>     java.util.Locale.getDefault() will be used.
> - Type:   java.util.Locale
> - Access:     read-write
> - Since:  Xerces-J 2.10.0
> - Note:   **If no messages are available for the specified locale the platform default will be used. If the platform default is not English
>     and no messages are available for this locale then messages will be
>     reported in English**.

Also I found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html) an example where in order to create a `Locale` object for the Russian language this code is provided:

Locale dLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ru").setScript("Cyrl").build();

I don't know if this could be useful. Just have a try and give me feedback about it!

Comment: still getting java.lang.NullPointerException :(

Comment: Could you edit your post adding the entire stacktrace of the error? Maybe it will be useful.

Comment: Have a look at this [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848106/java-jre-how-to-add-localized-resources-to-stantard-jre-resources) too.

Comment: There it is suggested to call the file **XMLSchemaMessages_ru.properties**

Comment: Hi everyone! Thanks a lot. All of your suggestions were correct. It's just that "http://apache.org/xml/properties/locale" is supported from xercesImpl-2.10.0 and I had older version. I updated the dependency, created file with "_ru" part and it works!

Comment: @Russell'sTeapot Thanks to you to have added the solution of your problem. It will be useful for somebody else too! Cheers!